# Значение слова "еси" в тексте молитвы

Tags: значение-слов

В молитве есть такая фраза: "... *яко Спаса родила еси душ наших*". Я нашла перевод фразы в Интернете: *...потому что Ты родила Спасителя душ наших.* Но такой перевод мне кажется неточным.

Что означает "еси" (есть) в контексте молитвы?

Comment: А. Григорьев. "Система глагола церковнославянского языка": http://academy.foma.ru/sistema-glagola-tserkovnoslavyanskogo-yazyka-chast-ii.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Еси - часть сказуемого - глагола в перфекте, указывает на  2 лицо (я есмь, ты еси, он, она, оно есть, мы есмы, вы есте, они суть).

Перфектная форма глагола -  действие закончено в прошлом, но результат актуален для настоящего. При его образовании должны быть использованы какие-то элементы и настоящего, и прошедшего времени. Допустим, «он принес», актуальность этого сохраняется какое-то определенное время до момента речи. Первая часть похожа на наше современное прошедшее время – «принесл». А вторая часть – это глагол «быть» в настоящем времени, который спрягается, форма, которая нам тоже достаточно известна. Если «я», то «есмь», соответственно известная церковнославянская формула «Аз есмь». Если «ты», то «еси» – это «иже еси» в молитве «Отче наш». Форма глагола «есть» – единственная из системы форм, которая сохранилась в русском языке. Есть еще форма «суть» для 3-го множественного числа. У нас это существительное, в процессе эта форма лишилась своего глагольного значения и стала существительным: суть какого-то явления.

Получается особая форма так называемого исторического причастия «л» – «принесл» и дальше добавляется форма глагола «быть» настоящего времени. «Принесл есмь», «принесл еси», «принесл есть», сейчас  в прошедшем времени мы говорим «принес». А если взять, например, глагол «строить», то эта форма причастия с суффиксом «л», которая образует это перфектное время, то у нас получится «строил есмь», «строил еси», «строил есть».

То есть первый компонент, о котором мы говорим, это наше современное прошедшее время. То есть наше прошедшее время получилось из древнего перфекта, просто глагол «быть» утратился как глагол-связка и таким образом утратилась и связь с настоящим временем – моментом речи. Поэтому у нас эта форма так называемого элеевого причастия, причастия с суффиксом «л», выражает как раз исключительно прошедшее время, без дополнительного оттенка, связанного с настоящим. Получается, что перфект – это достаточно сильное время – у нас сохранилось, только утратив глагол-связку.

Практически для понимания перфекта необходимо видеть эту форму причастия, которая стала нашим прошедшим временем. Отсюда, кстати, наше прошедшее время, как ни странно, изменяется по родам. Вообще, глагол не должен меняться по родам, это категории имени изменяются по родам. Прилагательные изменяются по родам, существительные представлены в форме какого-то из родов, а глагол вроде бы не должен. Тем не менее у нас есть формы «строил – строила – строило», потому что перед нами древнее причастие, то есть древняя именная форма. А глагол быть по формам: «аз есмь», «ты еси», «он есть», «они суть» в принципе можно восстановить.

Comment: Спасибо, Людмила, теперь всё ясно. Макс (из Австрии)

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо за исчерпывающий ответ. Грустно, что мы теряем такие красивые слова и выражения в которых заложено много глубокого смысла. Язык меняется, появляется много заимствований и это неизбежно, это нормально наверное и всё же необходимо уделять должное внимание родной речи, чистоте и грамотности, сохранению самобытности и красоте русского языка.